# VisualStudio javascript obfuscator windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, obfuscation

Hello I am looking for a java script obfuscator, as an extension to Visual Studio 2010 preferably with UI (check a bunch of js files and "obfuscate" them into one min.js)
I was consider in "YUI Compressor" tool maybe you could share your opinion about the best obFuscator for VS2010:

"the best":

1.Doesn't mess up utf-8 encoded letters (ąčęąčę)

2.Capable of combining few js files into one

3.size of minimized js then ease of use

4.ability(if possible) to minimise css ...

,5. free also what is gzip??(try wikipedia;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the talifun-web suite which includes a crusher module. It's always worked a treat for me. In web.config you list the files you want "crushed" into a single file (works as well with CSS as Javascript) and everything else is taken care of.

http://code.google.com/p/talifun-web/

Comment: @talifun-web how much % of code does this obfuscator reduce lets say if we have 100kb js file after conversion what size will be? also do you gzip your converted files?

Comment: umm how do you  use talifun library? download, and then add references to your VS project?

Comment: also when I do that I get this error "Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'appendHash'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive."